# Pin Floating Action Button to Toolbar/Action Bar

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, coordinator-layout, nestedscrollview

I have a CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView and FloatingActionButton. In the CollapsingToolbarLayout there is a ImageView which has layout_collapseMode set as parallax. FloatingActionButton is pinned to CollapsingToolbarLayout. When that layout is collapsed or scrolled up what happens is the image is hidden and even the FloatingActionButton. I want the FloatingActionButton to be visible after the image is gone.

Here is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/custom_color_2"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" >

        <com.eventizon.widgets.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewEvent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEventName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEventDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:text="sun, oct 4 - mon, oct 12"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEventOrganizer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:text="By - Pritam Kadam"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEventDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fragmentGoogleMap"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButtonOptions"
    style="@style/FabStyle"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/collapsing_toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Comment: Instead of anchoring your FAB to the bottom of the Toolbar, try anchoring to the top of the NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 

 ImageView imageView= new ImageView();//ur image view
            imageView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                    FloatingActionButton fb= new FloatingActionButton();//ur floating action button
                    fb.hide();
                }
            });
```

This is just a hint, you may have to try other events listeners.